# issue with JOIN three tables with an alias for the same column

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables:

> 1. date_info with the columns:- date_id,year
> 2. transactions with the columns:- date_id, amount, trx_type.

trx_type only can be 'credit' or 'debit'

What I need to display is the year, credit and debit as results. (if trx_type is debit should be called debit vise versa).

I can get one of them using the following. BUT can't JOIN it to get both values.

```
select * 
from date_info as dt 
         INNER JOIN (select date_id,
                            amount as debit 
                       from transaction 
                      where tx_type = 'debit') as db 
              on dt.date_id = db.date_id;
```

Can you please help me....

Comment: Try aliasing your transaction table, also as transaction is a reserved word you should be calling it [transaction].

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select D.[year]
,case when T.trx_type='debit' then amount end as 'debit'
,case when T.trx_type='credit' then amount end as 'credit'
from date_info D join transactions T
on D.date_id=T.date_id
```